# Will larger gutter solve overshooting problem?

Tags: roof, roofing, gutters, downspout, overflow

Due to the structure of the roof, the water from several planes goes into one spot of the gutter, which causes severe overshooting problem even with clean gutter, as one can tell from the water marks on the siding. The proposal I got is to replace the related gutter from 5” to 6”, downspout from 2x3 to 3x4, and add a downspout from the upper gutter to the lower one. Is it enough to solve the issue? Any other measures like diverter or splash guard needed?

I would like to confirm its effectiveness before moving forward, because I’m not living there, and cannot do trial and error. Is there any way to test it by simulating a heavy rain? A garden hose won’t bring enough water to the roof.

[image]

Comment: My opinion is to get rid of all the upper gutters,   The short little ones under the tiny wing roofs are especially useless.  In a hard rain the water may gush over the lower gutter. ( I would get rid of that too)  Hard rains are for short periods.  I prefer to have the water shed from my roof where it can be managed on the ground and will cause less damage.

Comment: I can't see the problem in the picture. Can you provide more pictures highlighting exactly what and where the problems are?

Comment: @RMDman How to manage the water on the ground? I have a stoop under the lower gutter, and the water washed away some soil underneath and caused it settled unevenly towards the house. Thus there is quite a lot standing water in and after rain. The water goes through the siding, the wall and into the garage and the crawlspace, leads to significant mold problem. I jacked up the stoop to make it level, but if I don't somehow manage the water, either at the gutter or on the ground, I would have the same problem again sooner or later.

Comment: @MattS I updated the photo, and the red circle shows where most water goes.

Comment: @ Bobby yan, I cannot comment on how to manage the water on the ground of your particular home. There isn't enough info, and this question isn't about  ground water management. My comment is simply that I would prefer to allow the water to come off the roof and concentrate on control and management on the ground.  Water on the ground never made a roof rot.

Comment: Where does the water from the upper gutter go - does it dump on the roof to the right and then run down to the problem area?  It might be helpful to add a downspout to the upper gutter to discharge directly into the lower gutter.

Comment: Is the short zigzag or two short gutters directly above the red circle connected to a downspout? If not, then that whole center/left section of roof is contributing to your issue (which I think is what you are saying). Does the upper gutter section just overflow along its length, so you may also have water coming directly down from it and not into the lower roof slope?

Comment: To me it seems the 3 things to do are: 1) drain the upper gutter so it doesn't overflow or flow onto a lower roof section; a dedicated downspout to ground for that would be nice to reduce the capacity needed in the lower horizontal gutter. 2) Increase the capacity of the lower horizontal gutter and perhaps increase its rightward downslope a little bit. 3) Increase the downspout capacity.

Comment: It seems like the proposal you got sounds reasonable. What about the drain at the bottom of the downspout on the right - can that handle potentially double the flow with a bigger downspout?

Comment: @Mark The upper gutter has no downspout or right end cap for now, and the water comes out at the right end to the roof. In additional to a dedicate down spout, shall I change to upper gutter to a larger one as well?

Comment: @Armand See my comment above. I'm not sure about the drain, let's try and see. It's buried in the ground, is there anything I can do about it? Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if something like this would solve your problem. https://i.imgur.com/3ZtZlBe.jpg (gah, why is adding pics to comments so friggin' hard?)

Comment: @Huesmann I got two suggestions about the downspout for the upper gutter. One is like yours, a downspout going to the lower gutter, the other is a dedicate downspout going to the ground drain directly. Which one do you think is better?

Comment: What's not clear to me from your pic is how the water from the "zigzag" gutter above your red circle gets to the ground.  I don't see a downspout from it.

Comment: @Huesmann The upper gutter has no downspout or right end cap for now, and the water comes out at the right end to the roof.

Comment: Oh, that's definitely not good.  As to the two suggestions you've received, obviously I'm partial to mine.  I can't imagine how you'd get a dedicated downspout to the ground, without all kinds of bends and such.

Comment: Is the "overshoot" the result of the water from that unfinished top gutter running off the steep roof slope so rapidly that it actually flies over top of the gutter, or is it the result of an overflowing gutter that can't handle the flow rate? If the former, then a downspout to the lower gutter will likely be adequate; if the latter, you'll need either a larger main downspout or a second downspout. Either way you most likely need to cap the end of the top gutter and route a downspout *somewhere*.